# Get sum with limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation, infinity

I have a sum $\frac{1}{2+a}$ which is only valid for $a \in (-\infty,-3) \cup (-1,\infty)$.

To express the some correctly, should I show the sum for the entire interval?

I guess I can say something like
$$
\frac{1}{2+a} \in [-\frac{1}{2},0) \, \cup \, \cdots
$$

The left side of the interval is $(-\infty,-3)$. If I put $-3$ into the sum, I get $-\frac{1}{2}$ and if I put $-\infty$ into the sum, it goes to $0$, so the sum must be between $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $0$, but none of the limits included.

But what about the right side of the interval $(-1,\infty)$? If I substitute a=-1, I get 1, so is the sum between 0 and 1, none of them included?

Comment: Huh? In what way is $1/(2+a)$ a sum? in what way is $1/(2+a)$ not valid for $a$ between $-3$ and $-1$ (other than for $a=-2$)? What do you mean by "express the sum correctly"? what do you mean by "the entire interval", and what do you mean by "showing the sum" for the entire interval? In short, what are you talking about?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have found the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2+a)^n}$ which only converges for $a \in (-\infty,-3) \cup (-1,\infty)$. The value is $\frac{x}{1-x}$ where $x = \frac{1}{2+a}$.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into the body of your question, instead of putting them in comments. As you say, the series doesn't converge between $-3$ and $-1$, so, if your interest is in expressing the sum, then you're done when you get $1/(2+a)$ together with its realm of validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $\dfrac{1}{2+(-3)}=-1$ while $\dfrac{1}{2+(-1)}=1$

so your function will take values in $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ if $a \in (-\infty,-3)\cup(-1,\infty)$.